# Asp.Net MVC5 website menu bar go collapsed when updating bootstrap.css from 3.3.7 into 4.1.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

I'm following an online tutorial, just started a simple MVC website project in VS2017 Community Edition. The view is using the default auto-generated _layout.cshtml, its referencing Bootstrap v3.3.7.

I tried to update the Bootstrap.css by replacing it with this one: (v4.1.1) https://bootswatch.com/4/yeti/bootstrap.css, however, instead of looking like this:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IeK9.jpg

it appeared as this:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9bIe.jpg[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvUIp.png)

The whole menu bar remain collapsed after upgrading from v3.3.7 to v4.1.1

Wonder what I did wrong, or how can I make it right.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, duplicate to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550955/mvc-bootstrap-navbar-not-working-after-running-nuget-updates/49048717  -- guess I already got my answer. Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC bootstrap navbar not working after running NuGet updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550955/mvc-bootstrap-navbar-not-working-after-running-nuget-updates)