# .Less files not rendering

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, less

I had created a web application in Visual Studio 2017.  I upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and now the .less files dont seem to being rendered.

I then quickly created a standard web application just using the visual studio templates and this displays correctly.

In my original project I then added an aspx page and copied the code from the template project and this doesnt display correctly. I have spent the best part of a day trying to resolve this but with no luck.

I have attached screen shots of both web pages and the DevTools pages.

**Non working page**

[image]
[image: Dev tools page]

**Working page screenshots**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [MVC bootstrap navbar not working after running NuGet updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550955/mvc-bootstrap-navbar-not-working-after-running-nuget-updates)

Downgraded my version of bootstrap from 4 to 3 as 4 breaks things in Visual Studio